# How can I create an avatar with number in the circle in css

Tags: html, css, avatar

I want to create a numbers inside circle as an avatar in the circle. MY result using the below css and my html did not end up with good output. can you help with this please?
 So my css is like below.

```css
.avatar-number {
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccFF;
}
```

```html
<span class="avatar-number">1</span>
```

Comment: why not working when I used the place-items:center; in my css

Comment: You spelled padding pading. I made you a snippet which showed the error in the code editor. Next time click the `[<>]`  snippet editor and see for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `line-height` to centre align horizontally and vertically.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ze1h7m6v/

```
.avatar-number {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three changes:

- Change `padding-left` to `padding` and
- Add `text-align: center` (for horizontal centering)
- Add a `line-height` equal to the `height` (for vertical centering)

**Working Example:**

```css
.avatar-number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ccccff;
}
```

```html
<span class="avatar-number">1</span>
<span class="avatar-number">2</span>
<span class="avatar-number">3</span>
<span class="avatar-number">4</span>
<span class="avatar-number">5</span>
<span class="avatar-number">6</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution if I understood your question.
You need to style a container, not the span itself!
[https://codepen.io/Zeldocarina/pen/oNNbJeX][1]

HTML:
`<div class="avatar"><span class="avatar__number">1</span></div>`

CSS:

```
.avatar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#ccFF;
}

.avatar .avatar__number {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 3rem;
}


  [1]: https://codepen.io/Zeldocarina/pen/oNNbJeX
```